# how can i change the b-spline curves from 4 point to 6?

Tags: c++, bgi, bspline

I have a code on C++ it's b-spline curve that has 4 points if I want to change it to 6 point what shall I change in the code?

You can check the code:

```
#include "graphics.h"
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
  int gd, gm, page = 0;
  gd = VGA;
  gm = VGAMED;
  initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
  point2d pontok[4] = { 100, 100, 150, 200, 170, 130, 240, 270 }; //pontok means points

  int ap;
  for (;;) {
    setactivepage(page);
    cleardevice();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      circle(integer(pontok[i].x), integer(pontok[i].y), 3);

    double t = 0;

    moveto((1.0 / 6) * (pontok[0].x * pow(1 - t, 3) +
                        pontok[1].x * (3 * t * t * t - 6 * t * t + 4) +
                        pontok[2].x * (-3 * t * t * t + 3 * t * t + 3 * t + 1) +
                        pontok[3].x * t * t * t),
           (1.0 / 6) * (pontok[0].y * pow(1 - t, 3) +
                        pontok[1].y * (3 * t * t * t - 6 * t * t + 4) +
                        pontok[2].y * (-3 * t * t * t + 3 * t * t + 3 * t + 1) +
                        pontok[3].y * t * t * t));

    for (t = 0; t <= 1; t += 0.01)
      lineto(
          (1.0 / 6) * (pontok[0].x * pow(1 - t, 3) +
                       pontok[1].x * (3 * t * t * t - 6 * t * t + 4) +
                       pontok[2].x * (-3 * t * t * t + 3 * t * t + 3 * t + 1) +
                       pontok[3].x * t * t * t),
          (1.0 / 6) * (pontok[0].y * pow(1 - t, 3) +
                       pontok[1].y * (3 * t * t * t - 6 * t * t + 4) +
                       pontok[2].y * (-3 * t * t * t + 3 * t * t + 3 * t + 1) +
                       pontok[3].y * t * t * t));

    /* Egerkezeles */ //Egerkezeles means mouse event handling
    if (!balgomb)
      ap = getactivepoint((point2d *)pontok, 4, 5);
    if (ap >= 0 && balgomb) { //balgomb means left mouse button
      pontok[ap].x = egerx;   //eger means mouse
      pontok[ap].y = egery;
    }
    /* Egerkezeles vege */

    setvisualpage(page);
    page = 1 - page;
    if (kbhit())
      break;
  }
  getch();
  closegraph();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to insert those points between the 2 inner points then you can simply get their coords with an interpolation method. If it lies outside of the 2, then you should calculate minimum one more control point. Also, I would redesign the code so it contains a b-spline interpolation function which accepts floating point coords. Now I'm tired to provide a full answer but I try it tomorrow.

Comment: thanks a lot in advance,, i will be waiting for the Answer,,

Comment: uhm sorry I've just realized in one of my app I've used Catmull-Rom Splines not B-splines. I tought it was B-spline. I don't think they are the same.:S

Comment: its okay man, then i hope some one to help me with it,,

Answer (score 0):

From your formula, it looks like you are trying to draw a cubic Bezier curve. But the formula does not seem entirely correct. You can google "cubic Bezier curve" to find the correct formula. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) contains the formula for any degree of Bezier curve. You can find the "6-points" formula from there by using degree = 5.

Comment: Include this as comment. This does not provide answer to the question.

Comment: http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-11-rendering-the-teapot-bezier-surfaces/b-zier-curve/